# Why is it that parseInt(8,3) == NaN and parseInt(16,3) == 1?

Tags: javascript, numbers, parseint, radix

I'm reading [this](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/) but I'm confused by what is written in the **parseInt with a radix argument** chapter

[image: table of parseInt(_, 3) outcomes]

Why is it that `parseInt(8, 3)` → `NaN` and `parseInt(16, 3)` → `1`?

AFAIK 8 and 16 are not base-3 numbers, so `parseInt(16, 3)` should return `NaN` too

[image: the first ten base-3 natural numbers]

Comment: Yet another issue that would have been solved by static typing (or at least not implicitly converting integers to strings) :P

Comment: @Navin This has nothing to do with static versus dynamic typing (as you note yourself).  The problem here is weak as opposed to strong typing.

Comment: When I saw the title of this question I thought to myself, "it's probably because loljavascript". Seeing the answers I judge my instinct to have been basically correct.

Answer (score 377, accepted):

This is something people trip over all the time, even when they know about it. :-) You're seeing this for the same reason `parseInt("1abc")` returns 1: `parseInt` stops at the first invalid character and returns whatever it has at that point. If there are no valid characters to parse, it returns `NaN`.

`parseInt(8, 3)` means "parse `"8"` in base 3" (note that it converts the number `8` to a string; [details in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-parseint-string-radix)). But in base 3, the single-digit numbers are just `0`, `1`, and `2`. It's like asking it to parse `"9"` in octal. Since there were **no** valid characters, you got `NaN`.

`parseInt(16, 3)` is asking it to parse `"16"` in base 3. Since it can parse the `1`, it does, and then it stops at the `6` because it can't parse it. So it returns `1`.

---

Since this question is getting a lot of attention and might rank highly in search results, here's a rundown of options for converting strings to numbers in JavaScript, with their various idiosyncracies and applications (lifted from another answer of mine here on SO):

- `parseInt(str[, radix])` - Converts as much of the beginning of the string as it can into a whole (integer) number, ignoring extra characters at the end. So `parseInt("10x")` is `10`; the `x` is ignored. Supports an optional radix (number base) argument, so `parseInt("15", 16)` is `21` (`15` in hex). If there's no radix, assumes decimal unless the string starts with `0x` (or `0X`), in which case it skips those and assumes hex. *(Some browsers used to treat strings starting with `0` as octal; that behavior was never specified, and was [specifically disallowed](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-E) in the ES5 specification.)* Returns `NaN` if no parseable digits are found.
- `parseFloat(str)` - Like `parseInt`, but does floating-point numbers and only supports decimal. Again extra characters on the string are ignored, so `parseFloat("10.5x")` is `10.5` (the `x` is ignored). As only decimal is supported, `parseFloat("0x15")` is `0` (because parsing ends at the `x`). Returns `NaN` if no parseable digits are found.
- Unary `+`, e.g. `+str` - *(E.g., implicit conversion)* Converts the *entire* string to a number using floating point and JavaScript's standard number notation (just digits and a decimal point = decimal; `0x` prefix = hex; `0o` prefix = octal [ES2015+]; **some** implementations extend it to treat a leading `0` as octal, but not in strict mode). `+"10x"` is `NaN` because the `x` is **not** ignored. `+"10"` is `10`, `+"10.5"` is `10.5`, `+"0x15"` is `21`, `+"0o10"` is `8` [ES2015+]. Has a gotcha: `+""` is `0`, not `NaN` as you might expect.
- `Number(str)` - Exactly like implicit conversion (e.g., like the unary `+` above), but slower on some implementations. *(Not that it's likely to matter.)*

Comment: So `parseInt` first uses `toString` on the first argument? That would make sense.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Yup, it's the first step of the `parseInt` algorithm: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-parseint-string-radix

Comment: I suppose `123e-2` gives `1` since it turns into `1.23` first, and then parsing stops at the decimal point?

Comment: @edc65, sure, but just running it doesn't tell me how it works behind the scenes. That came to mind because the table in the question shows a `1`, which I took as granted, even though it seemed it should be `5` or 12 in base 3. Which is if course what the result was, so I'll just guess the value in the table wasn't made with that representation of the number after all.

Comment: "This is something people trip over all the time, even when they know about it" -> am I the only one that thinks this should be a bug? Doing the same in Java for example will give you a `NumberFormatException` each time.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, it doesn't make sense.  Maybe it explains what we are seeing here, but behaving like that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The site linked in the question says: "if its argument is of numeric type it will first be converted into a string and then parsed as a number"

Comment: @DevidFarinelli: I don't think Sven is doubting the fact that the function behaves as you described. Just whether it makes any sense that it does so :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: *That* part of `parseInt` (coercing the first argument to string) makes sense. The purpose of `parseInt` is to *parse* a string to a whole number. So if you give it something that isn't a string, getting the string representation of it to start with makes sense. What it does *after* that is a whole 'nother story...

Comment: @Wim No it's not a bug and you certainly couldn't fix it without breaking millions of existing programs. And honestly, if you started filing bug reports for every single stupid decision in Javascript's language specification you'd be at it for a very, very, very long time. It's at least easy to work around it.

Answer (score 54):

For the same reason that

```
>> parseInt('1foobar',3)
<- 1
```

In [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), `parseInt` takes a string. And

> If *string* is not a string, then it is converted to a string

So `16`, `8`, or `'1foobar'` is first converted to string.

Then

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters

Meaning it converts up to where it can. The `6`, `8`, and `foobar` are ignored, and only what is before is converted. If there is nothing, `NaN` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
/***** Radix 3: Allowed numbers are [0,1,2] ********/
parseInt(4, 3); // NaN - We can't represent 4 using radix 3 [allowed - 0,1,2]

parseInt(3, 3); // NaN - We can't represent 3 using radix 3 [allowed - 0,1,2]

parseInt(2, 3); // 2   - yes we can !

parseInt(8, 3); // NaN - We can't represent 8 using radix 3 [allowed - 0,1,2]

parseInt(16, 3); // 1  
//'16' => '1' (6 ignored because it not in [0,1,2])    

/***** Radix 16: Allowed numbers/characters are [0-9,A-F] *****/ 
parseInt('FOX9', 16); // 15  
//'FOX9' => 'F' => 15 (decimal value of 'F')
// all characters from 'O' to end will be ignored once it encounters the out of range'O'
// 'O' it is NOT in [0-9,A-F]
```

Some more examples:

```
parseInt('45', 13); // 57
// both 4 and 5 are allowed in Radix is 13 [0-9,A-C]

parseInt('1011', 2); // 11 (decimal NOT binary)

parseInt(7,8); // 7
// '7' => 7 in radix 8 [0 - 7]

parseInt(786,8); // 7 
// '78' => '7' => 7 (8 & next any numbers are ignored bcos 8 is NOT in [0-7])

parseInt(76,8); // 62 
// Both 7 & 6 are allowed '76' base 8 decimal conversion is 62 base 10
```