# + operator is concatinating rather adding even after parseFloat method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In following expression

```
parseFloat((($scope.Product.cost/100) * $scope.Product.profit) + $scope.Product.cost);
```

+ operator is concatinating the values and i expect it to perform addition.

Comment: This is because you have some of string value, there parse all individually

Answer (score 2):

> ...even after `parseFloat` method

The `+` part of that expression **isn't** after the `parseFloat`, it's *before* the `parseFloat`.

You probably wanted:

```
(($scope.Product.cost/100) * $scope.Product.profit) + parseFloat($scope.Product.cost);
```

Note that `cost` in the above is *implicitly* converted to number when you use it in the `/100` expression, but you're *explicitly* converting it with `parseFloat` elsewhere. Those two things don't do quite the same thing.

I'd probably prefer to convert, then calculate:

```
var cost = parseFloat($scope.Product.cost); // or +$scope.Product.cost
var profit = parseFloat($scope.Product.profit); // or +$scope.Product.profit
var result = ((cost/100) * profit) + cost;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147168/157247) for a rundown of the differences between implicit string-to-number conversion vs. `parseFloat` (and others).

---

Side note: You don't need some of the parens you're using, the last line of the convert-then-calculate above could be:

```
var result = (cost/100) * profit + cost;
```

...because `*` has higher precedence than `+`. But the extra `()` are harmless.

Answer (score 2):

Convert each of the variables in your expression to number by applying the `+` unitary operator on each of them:

```
+$scope.Product.cost/100 * +$scope.Product.profit + +$scope.Product.cost;
```

As noted in comments, the coercion to `float` is implied for the first part of the expression by the `/` and `*` operators, but not so for the `+` operator, which will coerce the first numerical result to string unless the second argument is first converted to number as well.

So the first two `+` unitary operators are not really necessary.

Comment: Point taken, @T.J.Crowder.