# Why is this while() loop coming up as an Infinite Loop?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, while-loop, infinite

Just trying to figure out why the following code is an infinite loop?

```
var x = prompt("enter a number");

while (isNaN(x)){
    prompt("please enter a number");
}
```

All I wanted to do was to keep asking the user to enter a valid number until she does so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not updating `x` within the loop:

```
var x = prompt("enter a number");

while (isNaN(x)){
    x = prompt("please enter a number"); // <====
}
```

---

Note that this is one of those places a `do-while` loop is useful:

```
var x;
do {
    x = prompt("please enter a number");
}
while (isNaN(x));
```

---

Also note that `x` will be a *string*. `isNaN` will work with it, though, because the first thing it does is try to convert its argument to a number if it's not one. But note that `x` remains a string and so (for instance) `+` may not do what you expect. So you might convert it using a unary `+`, `Number()`, `parseInt`, or `parseFloat`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147168/157247) for details on those options.) Example:

```
var x;
do {
    x = +prompt("please enter a number");
//      ^
}
while (isNaN(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first line of your script, you ask the user for input, and assign this input to `x` (Say that they enter 'a', not numeric). Then, you check to see if `x` is a number (it isn't). If it isn't a number, the user is asked for input again. 
However, that input is never (re- )assigned to `x`, and the value of `x` remains 'a'. the `prompt`-command is in no way coupled with the variable `x`. Try this within your loop

```
x = prompt("please enter a number");
```