# Why does parseInt returns NaN when used with Array.map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, parseint

If I map through an array using `parseInt` it returns unexpected and incorrect results:

```js
console.log(["1234-04-23", "1234", "04", "23"].map(parseInt))
// => [1234, NaN, 0, 2]
```

but redundantly adding an arrow function wrapper works as expected

```js
console.log(["1234-04-23", "1234", "04", "23"].map(e => parseInt(e)))
// => [1234, 1234, 4, 23]
```

These two statements should behave identically, so why does the first one break?

Comment: Because `parseInt` takes more than just one argument. [Look it up.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Also, `Array.map` passes more than one argument to the callback. [Look that up too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because map adds a second and third parameters: the index and the array itself. See:

```
["1234-04-23", "1234", "04", "23"].map(console.log);
// => 1234-04-23 0 ["1234-04-23", "1234", "04", "23"]
// => 1234 1 ["1234-04-23", "1234", "04", "23"]
// => 04 2 ["1234-04-23", "1234", "04", "23"]
// => 23 3 ["1234-04-23", "1234", "04", "23"]
```

As you can see in [the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt), `parseInt` also accepts a second parameter as base, so you are actually doing this:

```
console.log(["1234-04-23", "1234", "04", "23"].map((e, e2) => parseInt(e, e2)));
// => [1234, NaN, 0, 2]
```

The `NaN` is because:

> `parseInt` stops at the first invalid character and returns whatever it
>   has at that point. If there are no valid characters to parse, it
>   returns `NaN`

*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147168/1525495*